# Copy document from sub-site to parent site automatically

Tags: document-library, site, sub-site

I have a site (home/vessel_schedules) which includes multiple sub-sites e.g. home/vessel_scedules/vessel_1. Each sub-site has a document library which stores all schedules for that vessel, for archiving and for sharing among the users. These schedules (documents) are saved automatically in the respective library using vba on a special Outlook account (there is a specific account used, which all the schedules are sent to from a vessel, the VBA code there distinguishes where they came from and saves them in the respective SP document library).

I have been requested that on the parent site (home/vessel_schedules), a general overview of vessels schedules is included, thus displaying the last schedule added for each vessel. I am searching an OOT solution (possibly) that will allow when a schedule is added in a document library, on a subsite, to copy the same document in the list on the parent site (and replace the last one of the same vessel). Since there are approximately 20 vessels and the documents are never edited by the users, duplicating the document will not be a problem.

I understand this is not possible with a SPD workflow, and I would be grateful for any "painless" solution or pointing me to the right direction. Thanks in advance!

PS. Keep in mind the documents carry properties which are displayed as SP columns (e.g. last port visited, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You need not copy the documents to the parent site. If the requirement is to display last document(schedule) added for each vessel(document library) on the home page, using content query webpart can be a good OOTB solution. 
For reference, 
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/sharepoint-2010s-content-query-web-part.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650512.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but currently we are using SP 2013 Foundation for testing, and I believe the CQWB is not included...